# "Clue" like relational database design: Schema must enforce entity multiplicity across related entities.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, uniqueidentifier, join

I have a business case that requires as much as possible to implement a database schema for the application which prevents an incorrect state for an entity called Trailers to be in more than one location entity, called Bays or Lots.

The code snippets for relevant parts of the entity models are below.

Essentially, my problem is I cannot figure out how to create a schema that will prevent a trailer from being in a lot, and in a Bay at the same time, while also keeping the 1 to many relationship from lots to trailers and 1 to 1 for bays  trailers.

I can obviously do things to mitigate this problem in the application, but having a schema that prevents this state is better.

Anyone have any thoughts on how this might be best accomplished?

```
 public class Trailer
{

    public int TrailerId { get; set; }
    public MaintStatuses MaintStatus { get; set; }
....
}

public class Location
{
[Key]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    //Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Bay> LocationBays { get; set; }
    public virtual Lot ParkingLot { get; set; }
...
}

public class Bay
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BayName { get; set; }
    //Navigation
    public virtual Trailer Trailer { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
...
}

public class Lot
{
    [Key]
    public string LotName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Location")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

   public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Trailer> ParkedTrailers{get; set;}

...
}
```

Comment: So as I understand it, a bay is a place you can put a single trailer, and a lot is a place where you can put many trailers. Perhaps a solution would be to structure your database such that a trailer could only ever belong to a bay, and that a bay could optionally belong to a lot. I'm assuming that even a lot will have some concept of allocated "bays" so you can find a trailer that you've put in there...

Comment: In SQL Server this is called a Check Constraint. A constraint is a statement that is executed prior to each update/insert/delete for a given table and will cause the calling statement to fail if the constraint statement would evaluate to false. In EF, there is no one to one constraint mapping as with PK's and FK's. Perhaps extending an existing class and adding a bit of logic to the committing function would suffice. My opinion is that SQL Server is very efficient with table constraints, I would put those checks there. However, you are likely to get different answers from other people.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Sadly the lot cannot have bays, but is a generic place for trailer locations. So this design would not work in a way that adequately represents the models in the physical world.

Comment: If I was to use check constraints, wouldn't the commits I attempt with a db.SaveChanges(); when using entity framework only conclude the data is bad after I attempt to saveChanges? This seems to be inefficient since I would need to wait till after I called SaveChanges before I could know if my transaction committed without violating any of the checks. In this application i am also writing data to a manufacturing data historian that doesn't support rollbacks like SQL server does. SO that means I would have to serialize the writes, check if saveChanges failed, then do something to fix it.

Comment: Would a custom validator in entity framework suffice to check column data on a linking table? Smething like **pkTrailerID**, **fkBayID**, **fkLotID**, ... I would think a validator checking for a numerical value > 0 in the opposing column might work to ensure I am not writing a value into two places?